# angular 17, add proxy in angular multiproject?

Tags: angular, proxy, multi-project

I tried to add the **proxy and Rewrite the URL path** according to the angular documentation guidelines, but without success, the docs I have followed here: https://angular.io/guide/build#rewrite-the-url-path .
**What is the correct way to add angualr proxy in an angular multiproject, with angular 17?**

Answer (score 0):

Try these few steps to add proxy configuration for angular in a multi-project setup

1. in your root project, create a file called - `proxy.config.json
2. Add the proxy configuration in the file:

```json
{
 "/api": {
   "target": "http:locahost:3000",
   "secure": false
  }
}
```

This way proxy API request to `http:locahost:3000`

3. Now in the `angular.json` file, under the **each** project, add the proxyConfig settings like

```json
"architect":{
 "serve": {
   "options": {
     "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
  }
 }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Cheers